# Prove by mathematical induction that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i}{2^i}\leq2$ for $n\ge 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, induction

I have this exercise by my professor that I have no idea how to solve. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

Using the method of mathematical induction show that for all $n \geq 1$, $n \in\mathbb{N}$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i}{2^i}\leq2$$

Comment: Is this true for $n=1$? That's usually how you start a proof by induction (for natural numbers)...

Comment: Yes it is true for n = 1. Then I have to assume that it is true for P(k) and hence show that it is also true for P(k+1). But that's where I get stuck. I think I need some sort of general formula for the summation.

Comment: ^^ that's the kind of information/individual thought that should be in the original post!

Comment: True.. I'm new here, sorry!

Comment: Oh no worries, just something to keep in mind for subsequent questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Start by gathering some numerical data:

$$\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=1}^1\frac{i}{2^i}=\frac12=2-\frac32\\
&\sum_{i=1}^2\frac{i}{2^i}=\frac12+\frac24=\frac44=2-\frac44\\
&\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{i}{2^i}=\frac44+\frac38=\frac{11}8=2-\frac58\\
&\sum_{i=1}^4\frac{i}{2^i}=\frac{11}8+\frac4{16}=\frac{26}{16}=2-\frac6{16}\\
&\sum_{i=1}^5\frac{i}{2^i}=\frac{26}{16}+\frac5{32}=\frac{57}{32}=2-\frac7{32}
\end{align*}$$

This strongly suggests that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^i}=2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}\;,$$

and you might find it easier to prove this equality by induction; it certainly would imply the desired inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to prove that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^i} = 2 - \frac{n+2}{2^n}.$$

Comment: Ahh I can see how that always equals to less than or equal to 2.. but really I have no idea how to get from the LHS to the RHS.

Comment: Use the induction. The step is really trivial. If you can't do it, please write what you did, and we'll help you get on.

Comment: I don't know what to do. What I've done so far is proving that a given summation is equal to the given formula. I have no idea of how to get from just a summation to a formula.

Comment: See what happens when you add $n+1$ to both sides of the formula. That's the step of your induction.